# How do you aggregate depth 3 documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm not used to mongoDB yet.

I would like to make them as below results using sample data.
I want to find the sum of each field by day.

Even if I searched through several documents, I couldn't find the answer.

**sample data**

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    parentId: 1,
    'stats': {
      'type': {
        'a': {
          'n:1': 2,
          'n:2': 2
        },
        'b': {
          'n:1': 2,
          'n:2': 1,
          'n:3': 1
        },
        'c': {
          'n:5': 4
        }
      }
    },
    time: ISODate('2021-10-12T05:00:00Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    'stats': {
      'type': {
        'a': {
          'n:1': 1,
        },
        'b': {
          'n:1': 2,
          'n:2': 3,
          'n:3': 4
        },
        'c': {
          'n:4': 2
        }
      }
    },
    time: ISODate('2021-10-12T06:00:00Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    parentId: 2,
    'stats': {
      'type': {
        'a': {
          'n:1': 3,
        },
        'b': {
          'n:2': 5,
          'n:3': 7
        },
        'c': {
          'n:1': 1,
          'n:5': 2
        }
      }
    },
    time: ISODate('2021-10-13T05:00:00Z')
  }
]
```

**result**

```
[
  { parentId: 1, 'n:1':7, 'n:2':6, 'n:3':5, 'n:4':2, 'n:5':4, year: '2021', month: '10', day:'12'},
  { parentId: 2, 'n:1':4, 'n:2':5, 'n:3':7, 'n:5':2, year: '2021', month: '10', day:'13'},
]
```

It should be grouped by parentId, field, year, month, day.
Multiple field counts make me hard.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is this one. Instead of `time: { $first: "$time" }`, I use `{ $dateTrunc: { date: "$time", unit: "day" } }`, it requires MongoDB version 5.0.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { stats: { $objectToArray: "$stats.type" } } },
   { $set: { stats: { $map: { input: "$stats.v", in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         stats: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$stats",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$stats" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            parentId: "$parentId",
            day: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$time", unit: "day" } },
            k: "$stats.k"
         }, v: { $sum: "$stats.v" }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            parentId: "$_id.parentId",
            day: "$_id.day"
         },
         stats: { $push: { k: "$_id.k", v: "$v" } }
      }
   },
   { $set: { stats: { $arrayToObject: "$stats" } } },
   { $set: { "_id.day": { $dateToParts: { date: "$_id.day" } } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$_id", "$stats"] } } },
   { $set: { year: "$day.year", month: "$day.month", day: "$day.day" } }
])
```

Part

```
   { $set: { stats: { $objectToArray: "$stats.type" } } },
   { $set: { stats: { $map: { input: "$stats.v", in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         stats: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$stats",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
```

is equal to @TomSlabbaert answer:

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                "$objectToArray": "$stats.type"
              },
              as: "typeObj",
              in: {
                "$objectToArray": "$$typeObj.v"
              },
              
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The rest are just cosmetic differences.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g329oAbXXwq)

In case you are not running MongoDB 5.0 replace

```
day: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$time", unit: "day" } }
```

by

```
year: { $year: "$time" }, 
month: { $month: "$time" }, 
day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" }
```

and convert back to a `Date` with [$dateFromParts()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the MongoDB version is 4.2.

Comment: Is there anything that can replace $datetrunc?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several different ways as the main need here is to restructure the data so we can properly `$group` it, here is what I feel is the most simple way to do it using various operators.

I will mention that if you're using version 5+ the syntax can be simplified as they added the new [$getField](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#mongodb-expression-exp.-getField) operator which allows you to access specific keys on an object. However as this version is still very new I choose to not use this for my solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                "$objectToArray": "$stats.type"
              },
              as: "typeObj",
              in: {
                "$objectToArray": "$$typeObj.v"
              },
              
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$values"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        parentId: "$parentId",
        key: "$values.k"
      },
      value: {
        $sum: "$values.v"
      },
      time: {
        $first: "$time"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.parentId",
      values: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.key",
          v: "$value"
        }
      },
      time: {
        $first: "$time"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            parentId: "$_id"
          },
          {
            "$arrayToObject": "$values"
          },
          {
            year: {
              $year: "$time"
            }
          },
          {
            month: {
              $month: "$time"
            }
          },
          {
            day: {
              "$dayOfMonth": "$time"
            }
          },
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f1mWGRLpV6K)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

If you don't mind, can you explain a simple flow?

Using this code, we would like to find the sum of the groups of 'a', 'b', and 'c' at the top.

Comment: I want to use this code to find the sum of each group of 'a', 'b', and 'c' of the previous depth.

Comment: I found a problem. If you have the same parentId and have data from a different time, you will be in a wrong group....
```
,
  {
    _id: 4,
    parentId: 1,
    "stats": {
      "type": {
        "a": {
          "n:1": 2,
        },
        "b": {
          "n:1": 2,
        },
        "c": {
          "n:5": 4
        }
      }
    },
    time: ISODate("2021-10-11T05:00:00Z")
  }
```